# programming challenge help (python)?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve project euler problem [18/67](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18) . I have [an attempt](http://codepad.org/7XVZqMC7) but it isn't correct.

```
tri = '''\
    75
    95 64
    17 47 82
    18 35 87 10
    20 04 82 47 65
    19 01 23 75 03 34
    88 02 77 73 07 63 67
    99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
    41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
    41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
    53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
    70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
    91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
    63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
    04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23'''
sum = 0
spot_index = 0

triarr = list(filter(lambda e: len(e) > 0, [[int(nm) for nm in ln.split()] for ln in tri.split('\n')]))
for i in triarr:
    if len(i) == 1:
        sum += i[0]
    elif len(i) == 2:
        spot_index = i.index(max(i))
        sum += i[spot_index]
    else:
        spot_index = i.index(max(i[spot_index],i[spot_index+1]))
        sum += i[spot_index]

print(sum)
```

When I run the program, it is always a little bit off of what the correct sum/output should be. I'm pretty sure that it's an algorithm problem, but I don't know how exactly to fix it or what the best approach to the original problem might be.

Comment: Paste your code here.  Questions with code solely in an external link are not allowed.

Comment: How does your algorithm find the best path? It looks like it just follows the largest number down from the top.

Comment: Start from the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the algorithm. I'll let you figure out a way to code it.

Start with the two bottom rows. At each element of the next-to-bottom row, figure out what the sum will be if you reach that element by adding the maximum of the two elements of the bottom row that correspond to the current element of the next-to-bottom row. For instance, given the sample above, the left-most element of the next-to-bottom row is 63, and if you ever reach that element, you will certainly choose its right child 62. So you can replace the 63 on the next-to-bottom row with 63 + 62 = 125. Do the same for each element of the next-to-bottom row; you will get 125, 164, 102, 95, 112, 123, 165, 128, 166, 109, 112, 147, 100, 54. Now delete the bottom row and repeat on the reduced triangle.

There is also a top-down algorithm that is dual to the one given above. I'll let you figure that out, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong. Consider if there was a large number like 1000000 on the bottom row. Your algorithm might follow a path that doesn't find it at all.

The question hints that this one *can* be brute forced, but that there is also a more clever way to solve it.

Somehow your algorithm will need to consider *all* possible pathways/sums.

The brute force method is to try each and every one from top to bottom.

The clever way uses a technique called dynamic programming